# Mask Password in ActiveMQ connection URL

Tags: java, spring-jms, activemq-artemis

I'm using JMS on a Spring boot client to connect to an ActiveMQ Artemis 2.19.0 broker over SSL.

In `broker.xml` I'm using mask passwords like `ENC(32c6f67da12342b0a7ad1702033aa81e6b2a760123f4360)` instead of plain text, and it works fine.

I tried to use the same mask password instead of plain text in my ActiveMQ connection URL like in code below, but it didn't work. I'm using this command to mask the password:

```
./artemis mask <plaintextPassword>
```

The plain text password is working.

Here's my code to configure the connection factory:

```java
ActiveMQConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(
        "(tcp://amq:61616)?" +
                "sslEnabled=true" +
                "&trustStorePath=" + trustStorePath + "&trustStorePassword=ENC(397e3aeeddf27c9783a3ab920d83e24da5b7d710df3b405f)"
);
```

The error which I get:

```
2021-10-27 13:10:15.243  WARN 17748 --- [-netty-threads)] io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer      : Failed to initialize a channel. Closing: [id: 0x07b0d96b]

java.io.IOException: keystore password was incorrect
        at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:2116) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:243) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1479) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.ssl.SSLSupport.loadKeystore(SSLSupport.java:224) ~[artemis-core-client-2.6.4.jar!/:2.6.4]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.ssl.SSLSupport.loadTrustManagerFactory(SSLSupport.java:166) ~[artemis-core-client-2.6.4.jar!/:2.6.4]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.ssl.SSLSupport.loadTrustManager(SSLSupport.java:195) ~[artemis-core-client-2.6.4.jar!/:2.6.4]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.ssl.SSLSupport.createContext(SSLSupport.java:99) ~[artemis-core-client-2.6.4.jar!/:2.6.4]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnector.loadJdkSslEngine(NettyConnector.java:624) ~[artemis-core-client-2.6.4.jar!/:2.6.4]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnector.access$500(NettyConnector.java:124) ~[artemis-core-client-2.6.4.jar!/:2.6.4]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnector$1.initChannel(NettyConnector.java:532) ~[artemis-core-client-2.6.4.jar!/:2.6.4]
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer.initChannel(ChannelInitializer.java:129) ~[netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar!/:4.1.39.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer.handlerAdded(ChannelInitializer.java:112) ~[netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar!/:4.1.39.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.callHandlerAdded(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:964) ~[netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar!/:4.1.39.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.callHandlerAdded0(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:610) ~[netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar!/:4.1.39.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.access$100(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:46) ~[netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar!/:4.1.39.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$PendingHandlerAddedTask.execute(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1474) ~[netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar!/:4.1.39.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.callHandlerAddedForAllHandlers(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1126) ~[netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar!/:4.1.39.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.invokeHandlerAddedIfNeeded(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:651) ~[netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar!/:4.1.39.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.register0(AbstractChannel.java:503) ~[netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar!/:4.1.39.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.access$200(AbstractChannel.java:416) ~[netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar!/:4.1.39.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$1.run(AbstractChannel.java:475) ~[netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar!/:4.1.39.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163) ~[netty-common-4.1.39.Final.jar!/:4.1.39.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:416) ~[netty-common-4.1.39.Final.jar!/:4.1.39.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:331) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.39.Final-linux-x86_64.jar!/:4.1.39.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:918) ~[netty-common-4.1.39.Final.jar!/:4.1.39.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.39.Final.jar!/:4.1.39.Final]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118) ~[artemis-commons-2.6.4.jar!/:2.6.4]
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: failed to decrypt safe contents entry: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.
        ... 27 common frames omitted
```

Is there may be other way to use mask password instead of plain text in the connection URL?

Comment: I have tried with a similar url encoding the trustStorePassword and it worked. What error are you getting?

Comment: I updated my post with the error log

Comment: Is the plaintext password `0etjq234NCTgBxP8dc4` working? What artemis client version are you using?

Comment: yes, the plain text password is working. I'm using Artemis-2.19.0

Comment: I just tried this myself as well by making a quick modification to the `ssl-enabled` example shipped with the broker and everything worked. The masked password was unmasked and used as expected. What command exactly are you using to mask the password?

Comment: I'm using this command ```./artemis mask <plaintextPassword>``` and as I said in broker.xml I'm using mask passwords and it works  but in spring boot application I'm getting error

Comment: Can you work up a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and push it to a Git repo somewhere so that we can reproduce exactly what you're observing?

Comment: @DomenicoFrancescoBruscino btw how did you find out the actual plaintext password from my encrypted sequence ? It looks not really secure somehow.

Comment: @LDropl I supposed you were using the default codec based on blowfish that is a symmetric encryption algorithm. The the default codec is just to obfuscate not to secure passwords.

Comment: Is there any built in codec to secure passwords ? asymmetric encryption ?

Comment: I would ask this in another question to be sure to get the best answers from the entire community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ActiveMQ Artemis Client doesn't support encrypted passwords in composite urls as `(tcp://amq:61616)?`, see [ARTEMIS-3543](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-3543). The workaround is to avoid fragments, i.e.

```java
ActiveMQConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(
    "tcp://amq:61616?" +
            "sslEnabled=true" +
            "&trustStorePath=" + trustStorePath + "&trustStorePassword=ENC(397e3aeeddf27c9783a3ab920d83e24da5b7d710df3b405f)"
);
```

Comment: It works, but if I have multiple brokers like "tcp://amq1:61616,tcp://amq2:61616?..." it still doesn't work. I see the issue is about this case

Comment: @LDropl you can append the other host/port couples at the end after `#`, i.e. `tcp://amq:61616?sslEnabled=true&trustStorePath=truststore.jks&trustStorePassword=securepass#tcp://amq2:61616,tcp://amq3:61616`